# str_replace() inside function

Tags: php

So this might be something easy, but I'm stuck. For some reason I can not get this to work, using a function with a str_replace to change/edit a variable which I can't seem to get to work.

**index.php**

```
<?php
    include("test.php");
?>
<html><head></head><body>

<? $a = cons(array("one","two","three"),array("four","five","six")); ?>

</body></html>
```

**test.php**

```
$header = '<form class="Poll" method="post" action="%src%"><input type="hidden" name="QID" value="%qid%" /><h4>%question%</h4><table width="100%">';
$md5 = '';
$question = array();
$answers = array();
$tips = array();

function cons($params, $tips) {
        $question = array_shift($params);
        $answers = $params;
        $tooltip = $tips;
        $md5 = md5($question);  
        $header = str_replace('%src%', $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'], $header);
        $header = str_replace('%qid%', $md5, $header);
        $header = str_replace('%question%', $question, $header);

        //isset($_COOKIE[$md5]) ? poll($VOTES) : poll($POLL);  


        /* using this to test */
        if(isset($_COOKIE[$md5])){
            echo "Hello";
        }else{
            echo $header;
            //echo $center;
            //echo $footer;
        }
    echo $md5;
    }
```

When I echo out $md5 from cons() it works, and when I print_r() $answers and $tips it works. The str_replace, is what I am thinking, is clearing out $header instead of replacing %src%. I have done alot of searching but everything I have come across, the users/tutorials are showing stuff like

```
echo  str_replace('%question%', $question, $header);
```

which isn't what I'm looking for. I'm wanting to keep the code somewhat compact instead of have duplicates and repetitive code. So not really sure what to do, if anyone has any ideas or suggestions will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Or maybe you're not passing the `$header` variable to your function to begin with, and haven't enabled `error_reporting` even though something isn't working.

Comment: `$header` isn't available in `cons()`. Try passing it to `cons()` or declare it as global.

Comment: @reeno if you post this as an answer, i'll accept it. I didn't even think about declaring $header as global. That fixed my issue. Thanks alot

Comment: I added it as an answer. I'm glad I could help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$header` isn't available in `cons()`. Try passing it to `cons()` or declare it as global.

Answer (score 2):

What you wrote looks like it should work, but I haven't tried running it. Check the result after every `str_replace` and see what values you see.

Alternatively, skip the replacing completely and just construct the string in place:

```
$header = '<form class="Poll" method="post" action="' . $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] . '"><input type="hidden" name="QID" value="' . $md5 . '" /><h4>' . $question . '</h4><table width="100%">';
```

Comment: I tried echoing out each time and it still didn't work, I was having a feeling I might have to build it in the function.

Comment: ahh well I thought it was echoing out and empty variable but forgot to comment out the ini_set('display_errors',0) but with yours and reeno's help I got the kink worked out.

Answer (score 0):

`$header` isn't accessible from within `cons()`, the same applies to all the empty arrays at the start of **test.php**
You'll want to pass them as an argument, or add

```
global $header, $md5, $question, $answers, $tip;
```

to the top of the function `cons()` to allow it to access the variables from outside of its scope